# Django HTML form not populating variables

Tags: python, html, django

I am trying to get the input of the forms by just using requests and no actual django form(I do not need to store this data in a database.) So I am trying to use `request.GET.get()` method, but so far I have had no luck with it. I am pretty sure that it is something wrong with my HTML, but I could be wrong. 
Here is my views.py

```
if request.method == "GET":
    lineGraphInp=request.GET.getlist('lineGraphInp')
    lineTableInp=request.GET.get('lineTableInp')
    print(lineGraphInp)
    print(lineTableInp)
```

Also, here are my forms

```
   <form method="GET">
        <h3>Choose: </h3>
        <select class="custom-select" name="lineTableInp">
            <option value="myPosition">My Position</option>
            <option value="myCompetitors">My Competitors</option>
            <option value="top100">Top 100</option>
            <option value="bottom100">Bottom 100</option>
        </select>
    </form>
```

and

```
<form method="GET">
                <h3>Choose: </h3>
                <div style="margin-left:15px;">
                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                        <input name="lineGraphInp" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="myPosition">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox1">My Position</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                        <input name="lineGraphInp" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="myCompetitors" >
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox2">My Competitors</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                        <input name="lineGraphInp" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="top100">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox3">Top 100</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                        <input name="lineGraphInp" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="bottom100">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox3">Bottom 100</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: why you make separate form for 2 input in one html template? and how you submit the data, I mean you didn't have button in your form?

Comment: Wow, I am just that dumb. I forgot to include the submit button. Thanks for you help.

Comment: take it easy, take a break usually help you realize a missing thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You have not specified form acion

Eg.

```
<form method="GET" action="/">
Content Here
</form>
```

Please make sure that you mention that **action** it will not work unless you will mention it

I think these only a issue..!!!

Thank You